# Hard Drive bay in Dell XPS L502X DVD-slot

Tags: dell-xps

I'd like to replace my XPS' cd/dvd drive bay with a holder for a 2.5" hard drive.  I know I've seen things like this, but I can't for the life of me find anything like this these days!  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We actually have a whole series of posts about this on the Super User Blog!

### [Part 1: Setup and finding the right parts](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/04/best-of-both-worlds-putting-an-ssd-in-your-optical-bay/)

### [Part 2: Installing and configuring](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/06/30/installing-the-optical-bay-hdd/)

The first post contains detailed instructions on figuring out what exact type of drive caddy you need to order for your laptop, and some other details. The second one covers the whole installation process. There should be enough information there for you, but if you run into any snags or have any questions, edit your question here with what you need help with and I'll add more info.

Answer (score 1):

Newmodeus sells them: http://www.newmodeus.com/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=358